# How I instantiate? Include code

Tags: java, interface

The compiler won't permit me to keep <X,Y> on the last line and I do not understand why.

How do I get such a generic construction to compile?

I tried changing the code to this:

```
 X a = new A<X,Y>(); // "Type mismatch: cannot convert from A<X,Y> to X" 
 Y b = new B<X,Y>(); // "Type mismatch: cannot convert from B<X,Y> to Y" 

 W<X,Y> s = new M<X,Y>(a,b); // no error
```

I am a bit lost - please help!

Comment: Can I just say: This code hurts my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of `M< X, Y >` expects to receive an `X` and a `Y`, but you're trying to give it an `IA< X, Y >` and an `IB< X, Y >`.  The necessary relationships are reversed; `X` is an `IA< X, Y >`, but not vice-versa, and similarly for `Y`.

The following compiles, but appears to be not restrictive enough for what you are after:

```
class A<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> implements IA<X,Y>{}
class B<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> implements IB<X,Y>{}
interface IA<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> {}
interface IB<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> {}

class M<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> extends W<X,Y>{
    public M(IA<X,Y> x, IB<X,Y> y){} // this is the only change
}

class W<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> {}


//To my check class code:

public <X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> void check() {
    IA<X,Y> a = new A<X,Y>();
    IB<X,Y> b = new B<X,Y>();

    W<X,Y> s = new M<X,Y>(a,b);
}
```

Comment: First you have to explain what "fix" means.  The question is so abstract that it is impossible to know what you are really trying to achieve; I can't see the intuition behind the line that the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: I want to create object of M with no suppressed warnings

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that it kinda defeats the point of generics if M is the reason for their generics.

Answer (score 1):

The question involves a lot of generic constraints that don't make sense. `M<X,Y>`'s constructor takes arguments of types `X` and `Y`, which are type parameters of the generic method `check` (that means the caller can decide `X` and `Y` to be anything and this needs to still work). So why do you expect `a` and `b` (or anything else for that matter) to be the right type?

If you want to ask how to change generics constraints so that it works, here is a much simpler thing (it just changes generics (but keeps `W` and `M` as they are) and nothing else from the original) that compiles, and is probably closer to what you wanted anyway:

```
public interface IA<X, Y> {}
public interface IB<X, Y> {}

public class A implements IA<A,B>{}
public class B implements IB<A,B>{}

public class M<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> extends W<X,Y>{
    public M(X x, Y y){}
}
public class W<X extends IA<X,Y>, Y extends IB<X,Y>> {}

//To my check class code:

public void check() {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    W<A,B> s = new M<A,B>(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I saw you don't want to do it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
W<X,Y> s = new M<X,Y>((X) a,(Y) b);
```

does work.

As Judge Mental mentioned, your problem is too abstract and it is difficult for us to offer meaningful help.  For example, in the `check` method, you are creating `new A<X,Y>()`.  What does that mean?  You don't define `X` and `Y`.  There would never be such a method in real code.